# Meteor - Publish error

Tags: meteor

I'm building an application where teachers and students interact. I trying to publish the classes for teacher/student relationship. How do I publish classes which contain the `teacherUserId` and the `studentUserId`.

Path: `publish.js`

```
Meteor.publish('classes', function(group){
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['is_teacher'], group)) {

    check(id, String);
    return Classes.find({teacherUserId: this.userId, studentUserId: id});

    } else {

    // user not authorized. do not publish secrets
    this.stop();
    return;

    }
});
```

Path: `class.js`

```
Template.classes.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        self.subscribe('classes');
    });
});

Template.classes.helpers({
    studentProfileId: () => {
        return FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    }
});
```

Comment: In your publish function `id` will be undefined. Also you're not passing a `group` to your `classes` subscription.

Comment: Hi Michael. The id is in the URL. Is there a way to use that? Also when you say I'm not passing a group do you mean a user group (is_teacher).

Comment: You get 'id' using `FlowRouter.getParam('id')` just like you do in your helper, it's just not set in the context of your publish function. As far as `group`, I would expect `self.subscribe('classes',groupName)` with some actual `groupName`.